# CSS: Element's relative size makes background-image disappear

Tags: html, css

I have a background-image that is 800x480 pixels. When my element has a fixed size I see the background-image, but not when the element has a relative size or a max-width.

**Working CSS script**

```
.audio-container, .settings-container {
  max-width:800px;
  height:480px;
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("../../public/images/Audio/I_Audio_BGK.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

**CSS script with no background image showing**

```
.audio-container, .settings-container {
  width:100%;
  /* Same result with max-width */
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("../../public/images/Audio/I_Audio_BGK.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

What can I do to show the background-image yet have the element sizes relative to the browser window?

By request, here are the parent DIVs

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" class="main-guy">
    <div class="screen-inside">
        <div class="audio-container" ng-controller="AudioController">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the parent DIV CSS styles

```
.main-guy { 
  position:absolute;
/* Same result if width and height are set to a fixed number */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
} 
.screen-inside {
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  height:60%;
  width:66.66%;
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML code to help demonstrate the issue. In your second (non-working) example, which ancestor determines the width/height? I.e. 100% of what?

Comment: Change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` it will work.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Care to explain why?

Comment: @showdev Position:absolute works relative to parent, having position relative and having height and width, but he hasn't provide us more code to explain.

Comment: @showdev check my answer.

Comment: @M.Tanzil - I'm working on the solution right now, and `position: relative` for the element's style is NOT the solution. I am closer with `position: absolute`

Comment: @Les Paul check answer know, with `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `position:absolute` in `.settings-container` to `position:relative` as your image in this case act as a `Child` for `.settings-container` and the image should be according to its parent. So `Position:absolute` will not work.

Check the **snippet**

```css
.main-guy { 
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background:#999;
} 
.screen-inside {
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  height:60%;
  width:66.66%;
  background-color:blue;
}

.audio-container, .settings-container {
  width:100%;
  /* Same result with max-width */
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(http://reservations.life/css/images/bg-01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainController" class="main-guy">
    <div class="screen-inside">
        <div class="audio-container" ng-controller="AudioController">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following HTML:

```
<div class="settings-container"></div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.settings-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: URL("your-image-here");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Results in a background taking up 100% of the width and height of the viewport.  It's difficult to solve your question properly without seeing the whole picture, but my guess is that you will need to apply `height` somewhere else in your document.

You may also run into issues with using `position: absolute`, but again that largely depends on the broader picture of how you're applying this to your site/application/whatever.